# canvas app being directed to weird URL

Tags: url-routing, facebook-iframe, facebook-apps

My canvas app has all started showing a 404 error from my website.  I have not had any success in trouble shooting how the app is being redirected a website page rather than showing the original splash screen to install the app.  Any ideas on troubleshooting this?

the app address is: http://www.facebook.com/#!/AyopaSoftware?sk=app_155882081129524

Answer (score 0):

You need to fully configure the application that hosts that tab, including the canvas url.